# LM35 connected to amplifier unexpected output

Tags: operational-amplifier, lm35

I am trying to connect the output of a temperature detector LM35 to the input of an op amp. The op amp will later be connected to an ADC. The goal is to amplify the signal between 8C (80mV at the output of LM35) and 40C(400mV at the output of LM35). All values under 8C(80mv) should be 0 and what's over 40C(400mv) should be 5v at the output of the op amp.

To implement this I used TLV2252 as a differential amplifier. The fomula:  Vout = (VoutLM35 - 80mV) * R2/R1. 
[image]

The output of the op amp should increase or decrease with 156mV for each degree in the temperature (LM35 has the output 10mV for 1C).
The problem is that between 10C and 34C the circuit works as I expect but as the temperature approaches 40C or 8C, instead of having 156mV variation at the output I have a smaller one. 
For example:

-At 38C I get 4.58V at the output, at 39C I get 4.69V (a change of only 120mV). Even more, from 39C to 40C the output increases only by 100mV.

-From 9C to 8C the output decreseas from 190mV to 110mV.

Why don't I get 5V at the output when the temp is 40C ((400mV - 80mV) * 15.625 = 5V ).

Thank you!

Comment: Link to the op-amp data sheet please. Your quoted number does not show up in searches.

Comment: Looks like a typo in the question.  The text says TLV2522 but the schematic says TLV2252.

Comment: SE supports HTML entities. `&deg;` for degrees, `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, etc. Earth symbols should be pointing to the Earth! (The symbol represents horizontal plates buried in the ground.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TLV2252](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv2252.pdf) is listed as a "rail-to-rail" op-amp, but the very first page shows a chart where this is only true if nearly *zero* current flows from the `out` pin. With `R4` and `R3` loading it down, this will never be true, so the extents are always attenuated slightly, leading to the behavior you are seeing.

This can be rectified by scaling the values of R1-4 upwards, at the cost of increased noise. Or pick a different opamp with better output characteristics, or one which can be powered from further rails such as -5v / +10v or +/-15v.